# How to set binary mode when using the built in windows ftp client

Tags: jquery, ftp, binary, slideshow, mode

Hi I have images on an ftp server that i need to show in a jquery slideshow but they won't show up in the browser and on searching, it looks like I have to set the ftp server to binary mode but am using the built in windows ftp client where i just drag and drop my files from my desktop to the server and i cannot find the option to set to binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the system is case sensitive. In my code the image names were uppercase yet the same names on the server were lower case causing them to not be recognised.